# AHK - Sleep inside a function doesn't work

Tags: function, sleep, autohotkey

The following code works as expected:

```
time := 1000

<^q::
    Sleep time
    SendInput {F9}
return
```

However, the following code does not (it ignores Sleep entirely), and I'm unsure as to why:

```
time := 1000

<^q:: 
    doKeys()
return

doKeys()
{
    Sleep time
    SendInput {F9}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example works because the Variable Time is accessible to the code contained within your [Subroutine (gosub)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm?).

[Functions](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm)

> A function is similar to a subroutine (Gosub) except that it can
>   accept parameters (inputs) from its caller. In addition, a function
>   may optionally return a value to its caller.

```
time := 1000

<^q:: 
    doKeys(time) ; Pass your variable to the function
return

doKeys(x) ; Set your function to accept a variable
{
    Sleep x
    SendInput {F9}
}
```

Alternatively you could declare a variable as [Global](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals) so that it is accessible without passing it to the function.

```
time := 1000

<^q:: 
    doKeys() 
return

doKeys() 
{
    global time
    Sleep time
    SendInput {F9}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the variable global:

```
time := 1000

<^q:: 
    doKeys()
return

doKeys()
{
    global time
    Sleep time
    SendInput {F9}
}
```

**Note:**
If you use `#Warn`, AHK will give you a warning if there are *common errors* like this in the code.

Comment: You need proper {} after the for loop, you currently only loop over the send not the sleep.